# How to remove a View component in react native?

Tags: react-native, view

I have View -> Button. I want to remove this view from the screen on clicking the button. Is it possible to remove a View Component, or Shall we hide it? or shall we make the view height to 0?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance?

As I'm new to React native, I couldn't do this. I wanted to set some prop to view like visible prop  of Modal. But I don't know the prop name for View component.

Comment: You should add a code sample of what you've tried

Comment: You mention not knowing the prop names for View. [They are all listed here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#props).

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine what "removing" a `View` means in your application's context. Your options are:

1. Conditionally render your `View`. This entirely removes the `View` when it should not be rendered and it will not take up any space.

```js
const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {show && (
      <View>
        <Text>Test by not rendering</Text>
      </View>
    )}
    <Button onPress={() => setShow(!show)} title="Toggle Show" />
  </View>
```

2. Make your `View` transparent. This will hide your View, but it will still take up the same amount of space.

```js
const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{ opacity: show ? 1 : 0 }}>
      <Text>Test by setting opacity: 0</Text>
    </View>
    <Button onPress={() => setShow(!show)} title="Toggle Show" />
  </View>
```

3. You can set `width` or `height` to 0, or both!

```js
const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{ height: show ? 100 : 0 }}>
      <Text>Test by collapsing height</Text>
    </View>
    <Button onPress={() => setShow(!show)} title="Toggle Show" />
  </View>
```

These options will all work to some degree, but it again depends on what *your application needs*. That said, Option 1 is conceptually the simplest, avoids potential side effects, and is likely to be the more performant for many uses.